# How to pass html as string for looping in another function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, loops, parameters

I am facing the following problem. I have a function which returns me JSON data on success. I am trying to make infinity scroll, so in this function I am preparing the html for looping in another function, which will do the work. The server returns me JSON as:

```
{ "id" : 6,
  "title" : "Store Title #1",
  "movies" : [{ "id" : 1164,
                "title" : "Movie 1",
                "publishDate" : "1993-01-01T00:00:00",
                "description" : "{long description...}" },
              { "id" : 8452,
                "title" : "Movie 2",
                "publishDate" : "1985-01-01T00:00:00",
                "description" : "{long description...}" },
              { "id" : 6451,
                "title" : "Movie 3",
                "publishDate" : "1945-01-01T00:00:00",
                "description" : "{long description...}" }]
}
```

Function on success:

```
     function onsuccess(data) {
        var libraryInfoHTML = '<h2 data-id="' + data.id + '">' + data.title + '</h2><ul></ul>';
        var receivedData = data.movies;
        var loopHTML = 
            '<li>' +
                '<h3 class="clear"><span class="icons video-library video-icon"></span>' +
                    '<a href="#" title="' + receivedData[i].title + '" data-id="' + receivedData[i].id + '">' +
                        receivedData[i].title +
                    '</a>' +
                '</h3>' +
                '<h4 class="clear"><span class="icons publish-date"></span>' +
                    receivedData[i].publishDate +
                '</h4>' +
                '<p>' +
                    receivedData[i].description +
                '</p>' +
            '</li>';
    infinityScroll(receivedData, loopHTML);
}
```

Infinity scroll function:

```
function infinityScroll(received_data, loop_HTML) {
    var i=0;
    var length = received_data.length;
    var items_to_load = 10;
    function loop() {
        var html_maker = '';
        for(; i<items_to_load; i++) {
            html_maker +=
                loop_HTML;
        }
        items_to_load += i;
        $('#container ul').append(html_maker);
    }

    function scroller() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height())*0.95){
            loop();
        }
    }
    $(window).scroll(scroller);
}
```

So the first function gives errors because "i" is undefined. I want to pass the "loopHTML" content to "function loop()" and I want it to loop the "receivedData[i]". I think I should convert "loopHTML" content to string, but how to tell unstring "receivedData[i]" places? Can you tell me better way doing this? Please don't suggest me plugins because I want to make simple infinity scroll. Thanks in advance!

Comment: No you just have to loop the array properly.

Comment: There may be a problem with multiple handlers getting bound to the scroll event - I think you are in effect adding a new handler each time data comes in.

Comment: It's apparently a bad idea to attach handlers to scroll anyway  http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/ (bottom of page) - they will fire very often.

Comment: thanks, I've fixed the issue. Thanks for the great advices, I've done it as you mentioned. Thanks!!

Comment: Is it possible to fetch JSON parts? I mean when I scroll down can I get only specific part of JSON which the server sends me, or I have to get all the JSON file and get the content I want?

Comment: As far as I know you have to get the whole file and then filter out the content you don't want. If you have access to the server side code then you should alter that to send only the data you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is to pass a function to infinityScroll that contains the received data and can take `i` as a parameter:

```
 function onsuccess(data) {
     var libraryInfoHTML = '<h2 data-id="' + data.id + '">' + data.title + '</h2><ul></ul>';

     var htmlFunction = (function () {
         var receivedData = data.movies;
         return function (i) {
             if (i < receivedData.length) {
                 return '<li>' +
                     '<h3 class="clear"><span class="icons video-library video-icon"></span>' +
                     '<a href="#" title="' + receivedData[i].title + '" data-id="' + receivedData[i].id + '">' + receivedData[i].title +
                     '</a>' +
                     '</h3>' +
                     '<h4 class="clear"><span class="icons publish-date"></span>' + receivedData[i].publishDate +
                     '</h4>' +
                     '<p>' + receivedData[i].description +
                     '</p>' +
                     '</li>';
             }
         };
     })();
     infinityScroll(htmlFunction);
 }
```

Then adjust infinityScroll...

```
function infinityScroll(loopHtmlFunction) {
    var items_to_load = 10;
    var i = 0;
    var html;
    function loop() {
        var html_maker = '';
        for(; i<items_to_load && html = loopHtmlFunction(i); i++) {
            html_maker += html;
        }
        items_to_load += i;
        $('#container ul').append(html_maker);
    }    
    // etc.
}
```

Note that this also checks that there is any more movie data in `receivedData` and will not add to the html any more if there isn't. However you may want to adjust the rest of the `infinityScroll` function so that it stops trying to scroll once there is no more movie data.

Comment: yes you understood me correctly but this didn't work for me.. I'll check again if I mistake somewhere else.